# get all tax rates in Magento 2 store

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-calculation, tax-rates

I'm trying to get all tax rates I set up in my store my custom plugin, I'm using Magento 2.

I found that in db all tax rates are stored in tax_calculation_rate, but I didn't find a method to get all data from this.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using the `\Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate` you can get a list of all the Tax Rates.

```
$getAllTaxRates = $this->taxRatesModel->getCollection()->getData();

foreach ($getAllTaxRates as $tax) {
    $taxid = $tax['tax_calculation_rate_id'];
    $taxCode = $tax["code"];
    $taxRate = $tax["rate"];

}
```

where `taxRatesModel` is an object of *Magento\Tax\Model\Calculation\Rate* class.

I hope this helps!